# Dominion: Throne Room broken in base game?

Tags: dominion

Me and my friends have been playing the base game of dominion and after about 10 games I’ve found a strategy no one can seem to beat. Three of the 5 standard sets have throne room and every time we play with it I win. Strategy usually includes 4-6 throne rooms, some draw cards like smithy, and some extra action cards like village or market. By late game I can cycle through a massive deck in a single turn about 50% of the time and usually buy a duchy and province each. Everyone feels there’s no viable counter to this strategy and as such refuse to play with throne room. Any suggestions for counter strategies that can make the game fun for everyone without banning my favorite card?

Comment: This might be too broad of a question for this site; but I can tell you that 10 games of experience is a very tiny sample size in Dominion. I have played over 3000 games of Dominion; and have not had an experience like yours. In your particular case, Throne Room by itself it not what is doing most of the things that are happening... Villages, Smithy, and Market are.

Comment: You should also specify what player count you are playing with. If you are playing 3 or 4 player games; then no one player should be able to get 4-6 of the same card most of the time.

Comment: Also can you please clarify the specific steps you are taking when playing Throne Room? It's common for newer players to play Throne Room incorrectly; in a way that could make it stronger than it actually is.

Comment: 3 or 4 player. I often go for the throne room early game while other people buy real actions, which does hurt my mid game. But I usually get at least half of the available throne rooms.

Comment: We’ve extensively researched proper throne room play. I always lay out the cards in a tree structure. The way we play, chaining three throne rooms lets me play 3 different cards twice. If I pull a hand with three throne rooms, a smithy, and a copper, I’ll chain the throne rooms to play the smithy twice, usually draw another smithy from those six cards, play that twice, and then play a card like village or market. Overall this nets me 12 cards, 4 actions. The five cards in the initial hand don’t always work well, but about  60% of the time I can do these ridiculous chains

Comment: Thanks. That all sounds correct; I've just seen a lot of people (myself included when I was new!) think that 2 Throne Rooms and a Smithy means you could play that Smithy 4 times, for example.

Comment: If you are pulling off the combo that often then I would be asking how well you are shuffling your deck.

Comment: In case you can't get a good answer in this type of Q&A format; I recommend checking out http://forum.dominionstrategy.com/; where people will be happy to go into all sorts of detail about the strengths and weaknesses of Throne Room and the specific games that you played.

Comment: "If I pull a hand with three throne rooms, a smithy" How are you managing to reliably get a hand with three throne rooms if you have (at most) six in your deck? Assuming no deck thinning, you've got (at least) 17 cards in your deck, probably more like 21-25? I think it's a hypergeometric I'd need to run there, but my gut feel says this is rather unlikely, especially if you don't have a decent number of smithies as well - which decreases the hit rate of throne rooms.

Comment: It would be useful to have the outcome of an example game - e.g. exactly what cards did you end up with in your deck and how many turns did it take?  Often new players underestimate the power of treasure cards and it would be useful to compare your strategy with e.g. Smithy-Big Money: https://dominionstrategy.com/2012/06/13/terminal-draw-big-money/

Comment: @ATyshka "If I pull a hand with three throne rooms, a smithy, and a copper": If you play a throne room with a smithy, you draw 6 cards, but you are also out of actions at that point. You cannot play another throne room or smithy. You can only buy now.